# Unable to fix "Reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java

im very new to everything about coding and was coding something basic on java and encountered the "reached end of file while parsing" error, I tried the only fix i could find (closing all brackets) but it didn't resolve it

I looked up how to fix it and I attempted to fix it and made sure all the curly brackets had correct a corresponding closing curly bracket

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessGame { 
public static void main (String[] args) { 
{
Random rand = new Random();
    intNumberToGuess = rand.nextInt (100);
    intNumberOfTries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win = false;

    while (win == false)  {

    System.out.println("Guess and Enter any number between 1 and 100:");
    guess = input.nextint ();
    numberoftries++;
    if (guess == numberToGuess); 
     else if (guess < numberToGuess) 
 System.out.println("Guess Lower!");

 else if (guess > numberToGuess)
 System.out.println("Guess Higher!");
 win = true;
}

 System.out.println("You win");
System.out.println("The correct number was " + numberToGuess);
System.out.println("It took you" + numberOfTries + " tries!") ; 
   }

 }
```

Comment: Yeah.. please make use of indentation.. then you gonna see which opening bracket is too much... (hint: the main begins with ```{{```, guess it should not)

Comment: Also your variables are not valid.

Comment: which ones exactly?

Comment: There are many things to point out here, did you code this on a editor like VSCode or something that will help you point out syntax error? If not try it.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessGame { 

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        { //this opens a new block of code with its own scope. you surely did not mean to do this, remove it
            Random rand = new Random();
            intNumberToGuess = rand.nextInt (100);
            intNumberOfTries = 0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int guess;
            boolean win = false;

            while (win == false)  {

                System.out.println("Guess and Enter any number between 1 and 100:");
                guess = input.nextint ();
                numberoftries++;
                if (guess == numberToGuess)
                    ; 
                else if (guess < numberToGuess) 
                    System.out.println("Guess Lower!");

                else if (guess > numberToGuess)
                    System.out.println("Guess Higher!");
                win = true;
            }

            System.out.println("You win");
            System.out.println("The correct number was " + numberToGuess);
            System.out.println("It took you" + numberOfTries + " tries!") ; 
        }

    } //this is just closing the main-function, not yet the class (but fix by removing the upper)
```